# Good gallery-embedding webapps for photo-sharing?

Tags: webapp-rec, photos, photo-sharing, embed

I want to create a page on my own website that uses a frame to display a third-party site and then upload photos to that third party site for display.  I'm not looking to hotlink, but rather redisplay a section of the other site.

Image gallery creation isn't trivial (Edit: mainly the file-hosting or hotlinking parts), and I'd prefer to leave it to the masters, but still have the embedded section be able to look reasonably nice on my own site.

So yeah, any photo-gallery sites out there that provide nice embedding services with robust text captioning?

Comment: It isn't your question, but image gallery creation doesn't have to be complex.  [JAlbum](http://jalbum.net/)

Comment: Well, I'd say that:  hosting images is a tricky business (allowing uploads of any kind, really), and hotlinking images on other servers is a tricky business, which kinda narrows down the field for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

If you're prepared to host some of it yourself, [SimpleViewer](http://simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/) has the ability to show a Flickr photostream. The **compact** style should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed [Picasa Web Albums](http://picasaweb.google.com/home).

From http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66969

> When you embed an album in your site, the album cover will display. Viewers who click the cover image will then be taken to view the album in Picasa Web Albums. Follow these steps to embed an album:
>
> 1. On the My Photos page, click your album.
> 2. Click Link to this album on the right-hand side.
> 3. Copy the HTML (Ctrl-C) in the 'Paste HTML to embed in website' field.
> 4. Paste the HTML (Ctrl-V) in the source code for your site.

If you want it to be dynamic (a slide show) rather than a static album cover...

> You can embed a Flash slideshow of any web album. It'll be automatically updated when you make changes to your album. Follow these steps to embed a slideshow:
>
> 1. On the My Photos page, click your album.
> 2. Click Link to this album on the right-hand side.
> 3. Click Embed Slideshow.
> 4. Choose your slideshow settings, such as image size, captions, and autoplay.
> 5. Once you've chosen your settings, copy the resulting HTML code (Ctrl-C).
> 6. Paste the HTML in the source code for your site (Ctrl-V).
>
> Once the slideshow is embedded in your site, people who click your slideshow will be taken to view your album in Picasa Web Albums.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to host it yourself, [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/) is embeddable.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Third Party applications like Picasa, flickr etc. provide Public APIs that can be used to upload or retrieve photos from their servers.

So what you probably need is a plugin that uses some of those APIs and displays a gallery that you can embed on your website.

So for example, if we take Picasa, you can use a plugin like [Pimax](http://www.codehandling.com/2015/03/pimax-20-embed-google-plus-picasa-album.html) to display a complete gallery of photos from any account. Similar plugins exist for most of the free Image hosting providers.

For the Upload part, not sure if many plugins exist, because users will need to login into their respective accounts (for example Google login for Picasa) in order to upload photos.

Anyway, I think trying to search for plugins is good starting for people who want build a similar functionality :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using a CMS like Joomla. There are  lots of Extensions that would allow this.

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=flickr

Alternatively it is also very simple to set up your own image gallery using Joomla.